# mediaelement.js not working on IE9

Tags: mediaelement.js

I tried to hit site: http://mediaelementjs.com/ with IE9 and I receive an error SCRIPT16385: Not implemented

mediaelement-and-player.min.js, line 40 character 495

Could it be the same issue described in: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/commit/b51f17bb717b
Would the same kind of fix allow a workaround to avoid the exception?